# Need to add multiple elements to search for a particular class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery and am currently looking in one type of element for a particular class. I need to update it to look in three different elements, but am not sure how to do this since I assume I will need to use an array?

Here's my current code:

```
$findRed = $("p.red", "#main");

if ( $findRed.length >= 1 ) {
    greater or equal to one
}
```

I need to change it so it will look for .red in either a p, div, or span tag.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector can simply be `.red`.  That will match any element type with that class.  Or if you just want those specific elements, your selector could look like this:

```
$findRed = $("p.red, div.red, span.red", "#main");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $findRd = $(":has(.red)", $("p, div, span", $("#main")));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$findRed = $("p.red", $("#main, #main2, #main3"));
//will look in main, main2 and main3

if ( $findRed.length >= 1 ) {
    greater or equal to one
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if ($("p > .red, div > .red, span > .red").length > 0){
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong.  using the > denotes that the .red class is a child of p, div, or span.  This is not what OP is asking for

Comment: Well the OP needs to clarify because that is how I interpreted it. He said "I need to change it so it will **look for .red in either a p, div, or span tag**."  That says to me it needs to look for .red as a child of either a p, div or span. If that is wrong, then so be it, he needs to clarify.